# Training loss does not decrease

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement autoencoders using CNN in tensorflow. Firstly, I trained my model on MNIST dataset and everything worked perfectly, I got the lower loss and when I ran the inference model worked perfectly (giving good output images). But then I decided to test my network on CelebA dataset, but my model fails and loss never decreases. The model processes fast and I tried decreasing the learning rate. Even though I decreased the learning rate, there is not much difference between the time it takes to train.

Here I will try to put all the code that I use

**Note I've set up GitHub repository as well, in case it's easier for you to read the code [there](https://github.com/Ersho/Autoencoders)

```
self.batch_size = 64
self.shape = shape

self.output_height = 64
self.output_width = 64
self.gf_dim = 64
self.c_dim = 3

self.strides_size = 2
self.kernel_size = 2
self.padding = 'SAME'
def encoder_conv_net(self, input_):

    self.conv1 = Model.batch_norm(self, Model.conv_2d(self, input_, [3,3,self.c_dim,32], name = 'conv1'))

    self.conv2 = Model.batch_norm(self, Model.conv_2d(self, self.conv1, [3,3,32,64], name = 'conv2'))

    self.conv3 = Model.batch_norm(self, Model.conv_2d(self, self.conv2, [3,3,64,128], name = 'conv3'))

    self.conv4 = Model.batch_norm(self, Model.conv_2d(self, self.conv3, [3,3,128,128], name = 'conv4'))

    fc = tf.reshape(self.conv4, [ -1, 512 ])

    dropout1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_prob=0.5)

    fc1 = Model.fully_connected(self, dropout1, 512)
    return tf.nn.tanh(fc1)

def decoder_conv_net(self, 
                     input_,
                     shape):

    g_width, g_height = shape[1], shape[0]
    g_width2, g_height2 = np.ceil(shape[1]/2), np.ceil(shape[0]/2)
    g_width4, g_height4 = np.ceil(shape[1]/4), np.ceil(shape[0]/4)
    g_width8, g_height8 = np.ceil(shape[1]/8), np.ceil(shape[0]/8)

    input_ = tf.reshape(input_, [-1, 4, 4, 128])

    print(input_.shape, g_width8, self.gf_dim)
    deconv1 = Model.deconv_2d(self, input_, [self.batch_size, g_width8, g_height8, self.gf_dim * 2],
                              [5,5],
                              name = 'deconv_1')

    deconv2 = Model.deconv_2d(self, deconv1, [self.batch_size, g_width4, g_height4, self.gf_dim * 2],
                              [5,5],
                              name = 'deconv_2')

    deconv3 = Model.deconv_2d(self, deconv2, [self.batch_size, g_width2, g_height2, self.gf_dim],
                              [5,5],
                              name = 'deconv_3')

    deconv4 = Model.deconv_2d(self, deconv3, [self.batch_size, g_width, g_height, self.c_dim],
                              [5,5],
                              name = 'deconv_4',
                              relu = False)

    return tf.nn.tanh(deconv4)
```

these are the functions for model encoder and decoder.

The main function looks like this

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(filenames))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls=4)
#dataset = dataset.map(train_preprocess, num_parallel_calls=4)
dataset = dataset.repeat().batch(batch_size)
#dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(batch_size))
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types,
                                           dataset.output_shapes)

next_element = iterator.get_next()
init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)

#print(next_element)
x = next_element
#plt.imshow(x)
#x = tf.reshape(x, [64, 64, 64, 3])

ENC = Encoder(shape)
DEC = Decoder(shape)

encoding = ENC.encoder_conv_net(x)

print("Encoding output shape " + str(encoding.shape))    

output = DEC.decoder_conv_net(encoding, [64,64])

print(output.shape)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(x, output))

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1e-5)
train = opt.minimize(loss)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

I call this train session in the normal way

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
  #saver.restore(sess, '')

  sess.run(init) 
  sess.run(init_op)

  a = sess.run(next_element)

  for ind in tqdm(range(nb_epoch)):    
      loss_acc, outputs, _ = sess.run([loss, output, train])
      print(loss_acc)

      if ind % 40 == 0:
          print(loss_acc)
          saver.save(sess, save_path = "./checkpoints/" \
                       "/model_face.ckpt", global_step = ind)
```

After all of this training starts without an error, but my loss does not decrease.

Here are utility functions as well

```
def parse_function(filename):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [64, 64])
  return image

def train_preprocess(image):
  image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
  image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=32.0 / 255.0)
  image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
  image = tf.clip_by_value(image, 0.0, 1.0)
  return image
```

Comment: I agree about the code being too big, but I've provided an explanation that might give clues on where to look for the problem. As I've mentioned my training loss does not change. It is stuck between some value +- 0.1, because of that, I did provide neither training nor validation loss graphs. If someone has any question I am glad to give more information if I missed something, like the one below.

Comment: Picking up from the comment about the output. What are the values on the output that are not in 0..1 range?

Comment: The values are between -1 and 1

Comment: Your loss function might not be taking the absolute difference, and since you can have positive and negative errors, the sum tends to converge to 0. Have you tried mapping them to range 0..1?

Comment: Where do you suggest mapping them? For showing purposes I thought mapping was not a good idea as the last layer of my FCNN has tanh activation function so range(-1,1) is not a surprise and I thought the model will learn to map values itself in (0,1) range after the training.

Comment: Your training images have values between 0.0 and 1.0, no? `image = tf.clip_by_value(image, 0.0, 1.0)`.Why don't you change this activation for a softmax, for example?

Comment: Changing `tanh` to `softmax` should make you loss go down to ~0.1 Tested here and it does. Let me know if works there.

Comment: Well, this decreased my average training loss from more than 1 (like 1.2 or 1.3) to 0.2 - 0.3 range initially but it does not change from the initial state for too much.

Comment: I'm running with 2000 epochs and the error goes from ~0.13 to ~0.09. Seems to work for me. Quite hard to get loss 0 and you also don't want that.

Comment: You are doing it with clipping the outputs right?

Comment: The only line I've changed was the `tanh` to `softmax`. Getting 0.08 loss now, started with ~0.14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing the activation function to softmax, which is more suitable to your image encoding:

```
image = tf.clip_by_value(image, 0.0, 1.0)
```

The loss starts at `0.14066154`.

Increasing the number of training epochs, the loss seems to get as low as ~`0.08216808`, which is reasonable, given I've only trained the model for a couple of minutes on a single Titan Xp.

Comment: you changed `tf.nn.tanh(deconv4)` to `tf.nn.softmax(deconv4)` right?

Comment: Yes. And `tf.nn.tanh(fc1)` to `tf.nn.softmax(fc1)`

Answer (score 1):

can you print the value of x ,outputs and gradient? 
My first thought about unchanged loss is:
1.if x is always zero,then the output keep same.the loss keep same
2.if x is not zero,but keep same in every step, and if gradient is always zero(the weight don' update),then the output keep same, the loss keep same
but because you can successfully run model on mnist, this show model is ok, so I suspect the problem is probably more about data.

Comment: I did try checking x and outputs but x is working properly, as when I try to run `plt.imshow(a[0,:,:,:])` I get the image. However, when I run `plt.imshow(outputs[0,:,:,:])`, I get the error `Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.` Can this be an issue? At first, I thought it was the problem of the lack of training.

Comment: This should probably be a comment. **can you print the value of x ,outputs and gradient** These are suggestions which you are giving to the OP so as to improve the question.